# how do i filter nulls out of this linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have code that iterates over a list of lists.

```
    public static AffiliateList FromDate(string date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("calling affiliates by date for " + date);
        AffiliateList al;
        try
        {
            al = new AffiliateList(DirectTrackXmlUtility.AffilaitesByDate(date));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return al;
    }

    public override IEnumerator<AffiliateItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (from ru in Inner.resourceURL
                select ru.location
                into date select FromDate(date)
                into listForDate from ru2 in listForDate.Inner.resourceURL
                select AffiliateItem.From(ru2)).
            GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Question: How do I modify the code to handle FromDate returning null?

Note: I would never have figured out how to write this query, but re-sharper did it for me from my nested foreach loops, and now I'm interested to see if I can make it work...

Update: Here's the final linq query, along with the original non-linq way commented out.

```
        return (from ru in Inner.resourceURL
                select ru.location
                into date select FromDate(date)
                into listForDate where listForDate != null from ru2 in listForDate.Inner.resourceURL
                select AffiliateItem.From(ru2)).GetEnumerator();
        //foreach (resourceListResourceURL ru in Inner.resourceURL)
        //{
        //    string date = ru.location;
        //    AffiliateList listForDate = FromDate(date);
        //    if (listForDate != null)
        //    {
        //        foreach (var ru2 in listForDate.Inner.resourceURL)
        //        {
        //            yield return AffiliateItem.From(ru2);
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
```

Comment: could you show me the foreach loops? I think it's easier to create a LINQ query from that than from that... thing.

Comment: How would you like to handle FromDate being null? Skip it? Use a default date?

Comment: Couldn't you use a `using` block instead of a try/catch?

Comment: @Nick, how would the using block work? I thought it was made to call Dispose after end of scope for something along those lines.

Comment: @Femaref, I put the original code in.  Looking at both, i don't think the linq way adds anything.  It's more of a learning thing at this point.

Comment: @Gabriel, the `using` block is short for try/catch. In the finally block it uses dispose.

Comment: `using` is short for `try/finally`, not `try/catch`.

Comment: so... have you got the answer you need?

Comment: well, he accepted my answer, so I guess he does.

Comment: indeed, and thanks; i assumed your answer was equiv of what i put in the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Inner.resourceURL.Select(ru => FromDate(ru.location))
                        .Where(d => d != null)
                        .SelectMany(ru => 
                                    ru.Inner.resourceURL
                                      .Select(ru2 => AffiliateItem.From(ru2)))
```

Forgive me for not using the query syntax, I just find the method chain much more expressive.

Also note that this was coded without any IDE so there is a possibility of error.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int date select (FromDate(date) ?? new AffiliateList())
```

or

```
from ru in Inner.resourceURL
select ru.location into date 
select FromDate(date) into listForDate 
where listForDate != null
from ru2 in listForDate.Inner.resourceURL
select AffiliateItem.From(ru2)
```